# how to remove the existing versioned file from git

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

I want to avoid my fabfile.py from being versioned in git.

I did these steps:

1. copied file to `fabfile.default.txt` file as backup
2. removed `fabfile.py`
3. `git rm --cached fabfile.py`
4. added `fabfile.py` into `.gitignore`

then committed the removed file including .gitignore file.

but then, if I create my fabfile.py again locally, it again shows up in `git status`. why? am I missing some step here? feel so dumb right now

Comment: Use `git rm` rather than `git rm --cached`

Comment: you might try adding `fabfile.py*` to `.gitignore`

Comment: @Nhor what does * do?

Comment: it ignores all the files with specified name

Comment: @Nhor I know it. see step 4.

Comment: does the `fabfile.py` exist in the root directory?

Comment: i know it exists, i'm just asking if it's in your root or maybe a little bit deeper in some directory. if so you'll need to add `fabfile.py*` or `path/to/fabfile.py` to `.gitignore`

Comment: did you commit after git rm filename ?

Comment: @Nhor oh got you, yes it is in root directory

Comment: @Holloway thanks, it did it

Answer (score 1):

Use `git rm fabfile.py`. `git rm --cached fabfile.py` will only remove it from the index. `git rm` will remove it from the index and working tree. You then commit the removal as you would an add.

If you want to keep the file (and ignore it) back it up somewhere first. (I'm sure the comments will come up with a more elegant way if there is one)

If you want to remove all history of the file it's a much more involved task and best avoided.

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm).

Answer (score 0):

I think the steps should be these :

1. cp to backup
2. git rm fabfile.py
3. git commit
4. add path-to-fabfile.py to .gitignore
5. recreate backed up file
6. git status should ignore this.

Comment: 4. added fabfile.py into .gitignore